# Where is the ckeditor toolbar configurator?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a newly installed current instance of ckeditor.

The docs say, "The new toolbar utility, which you can find in your CKEditor distribution package, makes configuring an accessible toolbar a breeze. It is the most recommended way to set up the editor toolbar."

Where can I find this new toolbar utility? I don't see it anywhere.

Barring that, is there some more detailed documentation on what all the toolbar button settings are? I downloaded the "standard" set. In the config.js file in the toolbar settings it says there should be a "colors" item, but I don't see it.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar Configurator will be available in each official CKEditor installation package starting from CKEditor **4.5** (which is the next major release coming up).

For now, open the "Toolbar Configurations" sample available in your CKEditor folder (/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html). It contains the automatically generated toolbar configuration for *your* editor package. You can copy the config and then customize as you see fit, re-arranging the toolbar groups and buttons or removing them.

As for why `'colors'` is there -- it's because in the toolbar groups configuration all default groups are listed, including the unused ones.

Plugins usually define a group that their button should belong to, so if you were to add a new plugin to your build (or say, a new plugin would be added to the CKEditor package as a new feature) you could easily forget that you also need to add a new toolbar group to your existing configuration. So it's for automation -- when a new plugin gets installed, its button will automatically appear in the toolbar without further configuration requirements.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, and also for your extra comments at the ckeditor support forum.